# How to pull current values alongside old values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What would be the most efficient way of pulling the current value of one field from a table alongside all of the old values?

My current solution is to join the table to itself on the max date, but this has proven slow.

ID remains constant but name can change so the table looks like this:

```
DATE        ID   NAME     VALUE
2019-04-30  101  JEFFREY  abc
2019-05-31  101  FRANK    bcd
2019-06-30  101  ROBERT   cde
2019-05-31  102  SAM      bcd
2019-06-30  102  JILL     cde
```

Current (slow) solution:

```sql
select 
curr.NAME as 'CURRENT_NAME',
table1.*

from table1
inner join table1 curr 
on (table1.ID = curr.ID and curr.DATE=select(max(DATE) from table1))
```

I want an output like this:

```
CURRENT_NAME  DATE        ID   NAME     VALUE
ROBERT        2019-04-30  101  JEFFREY  abc
ROBERT        2019-05-31  101  FRANK    bcd
ROBERT        2019-06-30  101  ROBERT   cde
JILL          2019-05-31  102  SAM      bcd
JILL          2019-06-30  102  JILL     cde
```

The current name would be whichever name is on the highest date for each "ID"

**The dates are consistent so 2019-06-30 will be the max date for every ID** until July's data has been entered then it will be 2019-07-31

Comment: SQL-Server, I added the tag, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the subquery:

```
select max(date) from tablename
```

in the `ON` clause which might be executed for each matching of the rows, use it once in a subquery which returns all the latest names and join this to the table:

```
select
  tt.name current_name, t.* 
from tablename t inner join (
  select id, name
  from tablename  
  where date = (select max(date) from tablename)
) tt on tt.id = t.id
```

This code assumes that for all ids there is **the same maximum date** as you mention in your question.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b81a0f8211c23ffc6948095d5c0d77f).
Results:

```
> current_name | DATE                |  ID | NAME    | VALUE
> :----------- | :------------------ | --: | :------ | :----
> ROBERT       | 30/04/2019 00:00:00 | 101 | JEFFREY | abc  
> ROBERT       | 31/05/2019 00:00:00 | 101 | FRANK   | bcd  
> ROBERT       | 30/06/2019 00:00:00 | 101 | ROBERT  | cde  
> JILL         | 31/05/2019 00:00:00 | 102 | SAM     | bcd  
> JILL         | 30/06/2019 00:00:00 | 102 | JILL    | cde
```

Comment: This does work, and it is faster, but only by about 5%, but I definitely appreciate the input, for now I'll use your method!

Comment: Do you have any index on id or date? If not I think they you should, they would help. Now: you need the query `select max(date) from tablename` but to be executed only once, as the code does and then you need the join. I can't think of anything more efficient.

Comment: Well, I'm clearly new to this! I forgot to add the idexes. Now it runs in half the time of my original query. You have been a HUGE help

Answer (score 0):

Your query is overly complicated.  You don't need the `join`:

```
select curr.NAME as CURRENT_NAME,
       t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.date = (select(max(tt1.DATE) from table1 tt1);
```

You should not use single quotes for column aliases.  They should only be used for string and date constants.

EDIT:

Oh, you want the most recent values included.  Use window functions:

```
select t1.*,
       first_value(name) over (partition by id order by date desc) as current_name
from table1 t1;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(id, date desc, name)`.

Use `asc` if you want the original value (it is unclear from the question).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it is not a bad assumption as the OP says in the question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: what's wrong about the syntax? The non-standard column alias apparently works for Jeffrey as that (incorrect) style is part of the question as well

Comment: I tried to run it but I'm getting a "FIRST_VALUE is not a recognized built-in function name" issue.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . . . You are probably using an older version.

Answer (score 0):

you can use top with ties:

```
select top 1 with ties
    curr.NAME as 'CURRENT_NAME',table1.*
from table1
order by curr.DATE desc
```